# CSharp - Calling a functions without params - error 33 no overload for 'foo' matches delegate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, visual-studio-2008

I've two piece of code. One it's working and the other no, i really don't know c# and google did't help me figure out much. Hopefully someone can explain what is the problem.

**Edit** - d is `public delegate List<CustomObj> SearchFoo(string a, string b);`

Why this piece of code works

```
d = foo;

private List<CustomObj> foo(string a, string b)
        { ... }
```

and this one no?

```
d = foo;

private List<CustomObj> foo(string a, string b, string c)
        { ... }
```

The first piece of code is running without a problem and when the foo function is called `a = ""` and `b = null`, i dont know why is doing that.

The second piece of code it returns an error:

```
Error   33  No overload for 'foo' matches delegate 'Core.Panels.ListFooPannels.SearchFoo'   C:\Foo\Functionalities\Foo\FooForm.cs
```

The project is developed in Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks,
Giacomo.

Comment: How the delegate `Core.Panels.ListFooPannels.SearchFoo` is defined? (I assume that `d` is a delegate of that type, am I right?)

Comment: You need to show us the type of `d`

Comment: Okay probably the error is caused by delegate

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko yes, it's a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate is expecting two parameters:

```
public delegate List<CustomObj> SearchFoo(string a, string b);
```

A string A and a string B

```
d = foo;

private List<CustomObj> foo(string a, string b, string c)
        { ... }
```

When you make this, you have 3 parameters in foo, but your delegate is expecting only 2, that's why you get an exception.

Comment: Yes, thanks you so much. Now i've to figure out what delegate does and means!

Comment: No problem! I would suggest start with the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/